# Eloquent relationships in Laravel 4

Tags: php, orm, laravel, table-relationships

I'm trying to make a mini CMS-type component and I have three models:

**Page.php**

```
class Page extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'pages';

    public function content() {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('Content', 'PageGroup');
    }

    public function groups() {
        return $this->hasMany('PageGroup');
    }
}
```

**PageGroup.php**

```
class PageGroup extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'page_groups'

    public function group() {
        return $this->hasMany("Content");
    }
}
```

**Content.php**

```
class Content extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'content';

    public function content() {
        return $this->hasMany("Content");
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
I've set up my relationship models with the correct relationships.

```
$page = Page::find(1);
$page_group = $page->groups()->where('id', '=', 1)->get();
```

Returns the `PageGroup` collection belonging to the `Page`. I guess my new question is if it's possible to get a collection from that collection... Something like:

```
$content = $page_group->content;
```

Because that returns:

```
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$content
```

Does this make any sense? I apologize for the newbie question; I'm just getting into Laravel!

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is - are you getting an error message? There's nothing in the code you've given describing the relationships - try http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships? That's a good place to start.

Comment: My question is the best way to create this relationship in Laravel 4. How do I build the models? I apologize if this is a very low-level question.

Comment: Read the link given by Kryten, then you will know that example call you wrote above will not work. Setup relationships as described in docs and come back if you have further questions.

Comment: I updated my question with some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like an idiot.

The method chain `$page->groups()->where("id", "=", 1)->get()->content;` will not work because `$page->groups()->where("id", "=", 1);` returns a list of rows!

`$page->groups()->where("id", "=", 1)->first()->content` will work.

Comment: Yes, and with Eloquent it may be even more eloquent: $page->groups()->find(1)->content;